# Add import duty to prices

Tags: magento-1.7, import, taxes

I've set up a multicurrency shop with Magento (version 1.7.0.2) where all prices are set in euros. But people from the US should be able to pay in dollars.

The prices are simply converted from euros to dollars with the currency exchange rate.

The problem is that for products sold in the USA a 0.5% import duty tax must be added to the price. For some products, this is different (Cacao is 9%).

I have already added an extension that allows me to add a factor to the currency rate, which I use to add 3% to the rate because of exchange costs when being paid in dollars.

How could I add this import duty fee? Adding them as a regular tax might confuse consumers. Also, I need to apply the state and county taxes to the value of the price with the import duty tax included, not excluded. So a normal tax rule does not suffice.

I'd like to have a fixed product tax, but instead of a fixed number, a percentage, that would be great.

Is such a thing possible? How do other Magento stores usually handle import duties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you already cheked http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dutycalculator-charge-international-customers-import-duty-taxes-upfront.html

Comment: it's too advanced and thus too expensive for the minor feature I actually need. It's like buying a new car because you needed a tire.

Comment: Then I would take one of the free modules that lets you add a surcharge to the cart total and customise it for your needs.